# Unable to open SQLite database file from local data store of UWP app

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#the-minimum-version-of-your-project-targets-the-fall-creators-update) section of this official MSDN tutorial: [Use a SQLite database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) but I'm getting the following error:

**REMARK**: There are many online posts related (or similar) to this issue but none seems to have a solution. Most of these posts are a few years old so I thought this issue would have been resolved by now. Moreover, the above mentioned tutorial is using [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) Class library project, as well. And the online posts regarding the issue do not have `.NET Standard` involved. So, I was wondering if the issue is caused by the use of `.NET Standard` library. Regardless, a solution will be greatly appreciated.

> > SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

**Error occurs at line db.Open() of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#initialize-the-sqlite-database) code**:

```
public static void InitializeDatabase()
{
    using (SqliteConnection db =
        new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
    {
        db.Open();

        String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT " +
            "EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";

        SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

        createTable.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

NOTES:

1. The line just below the above code reads: `This code creates the SQLite database and stores it in the application's local data store.` That means the app should have access to that local data store.
2. I'm using latest version `16.3.5` of `VS2019` on `Windows 10`. The target version on the project is selected as `Windows 10 1903` and min version as `Windows 10 1903`

**UPDATE**

1. This similar official 3 years old [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/windows-developer-blog-samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLiteSample) works fine. So, the problem seems to be related to newer versions of `.NET Core`. But I need to use latest version of .NET Core for other features my app is using that are not available in the older versions.
2. I also tried this similar old tutorial, but it did not on new version of `.NET Core` work either - giving exact same error.
3. The old problem reported in 2016 [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/263) to `Microsoft` seems to have resurfaced again with the new version of .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding, `SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db")` can not create a Sqlite file, but access the existing Sqlite database file through the path.

<del>So you need to create a valid `sqliteSample.db` file and place it in the root directory of the UWP project. Select the `content` in the **Properties -> Build operation** to ensure it will be loaded into the application directory.</del>

**Update**

Please create the `sqliteSample.db` file in `LocalFolder` first.

```cs
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sqliteSample.db", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Then use the path to access the database file

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqliteSample.db");
using (SqliteConnection db =
    new SqliteConnection($"Filename={path}"))
{
    // ...
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Now I get this error on line `createTable.ExecuteReader();` of the code: `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 8: attempt to write a readonly database'.'`. I went to Windows explorer to checked the permissions of the db file and it is NOT read-only (that is, it is write-able).

Comment: The reason for this problem is that the sqlite database file built into the UWP project will be placed in a folder during the generation process, and the files in the folder cannot be modified. I am sorry for this problem, I have modified the answer, please check

Comment: @RichardZhangMSFT Your updated suggestion would work if the project is not using `.NET Standard` class library `DataAccess`. But since `SQLite` related code is to be included in the DataAccess library, how do we use `ApplicationData` class there since there is no `Windows.Storage` namespace there. Please advise.

Comment: Hi, You don't have to put the process of creating a file in the class library. For example, you can create a file on UWP app and pass the file path parameter to the `InitializeDatabase()` method to initialize the database in this way.

Comment: @RichardZhangMSFT Your suggestions worked (thank you). You are the best.

Comment: Hi @nam , We have updated the documentation on creating a Sqlite database, this is [new content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#initialize-the-sqlite-database), thank you.

Comment: @RichardZhangMSFT Thank you for letting me know. Good job. I'm glad my post triggered this change to the official documentation.